# How to reinstall Windows when CDROM isn't working

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Windows XP machine that I want to reinstall.
However, the CDROM isn't working now. (always reading and reading but never starts) and I have no floppy disk drive.

How do I reinstall Windows then?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Superuser: Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)