# Install Windows XP from a pen drive containing an ISO file?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)

I want to install Windows XP using my pen drive which has an ISO of Windows XP!
I have tried googling, but the results were confusing. Some of them were how to install Windows XP in a pen drive and all. Can you give me a link that I could refer?

Comment: Yes, exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum, you need to extract the files from the .iso file first. There are plenty of questions and answers about this on this site. Just use the search bar or tags or look at the related questions which appear next to your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

[BootMyIso](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-multiboot-usb/) boots ISO from USB pen drives.

Just drag and drop the ISO onto your USB stick, update the grub menu with Notepad or Notepad++ to add it to the boot menu, and you can boot multiple ISOs from one stick.

Comment: i'm not sure that method can boot Windows-based ISOs.  if you would, please repost this on the duplicate with some basic instructions (eg an example Grub configuration), and delete this post.  thanks!