# How to install an OS on a nettop?

Tags: nettop

I order a "Giada Slim N10" without an OS. It does not have a CD drive so I understand i need to install an OS from a USB. how do you the windows version that runs from a USB? and is there an Open Source alternative

EDIT: The device arrived. It has a freeDOS OS and I don't know how to reach the USB I connected to it that has the installation for windows. please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Windows 7 from USB](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb), also: WinXP: [Installing windows xp through pen drive](http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive) Linux: [Booting Linux off USB Pendrives](http://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives)

Comment: How do I start a bounty on the question?

Comment: idober, from the FAQ: "Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you boot the computer there should be an option for "Select Boot Device" typically on most machines I have seen this is selected by pressing F12.

You should be able to plug in your USB device, boot your computer then hopefully you will see this "Select Boot Device" option and press that key.  After that you should be able to see a list of devices which should include your USB key, selecting that and pressing enter should boot the USB device.

Alternatively you should be able to go into the BIOS (generally by pressing either F2 or the Delete key a few seconds after power up) search around for a "Boot" option where you should be able to change the order of devices to make it look at the USB device first.  You'll need to remember which order the devices are in and change them back after the install is complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install Windows from a USB, there many online guides instructing you on how to do it.

You will need:

- Windows 7 Image
- 4GB USB
- Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool

For an open source alternative, you can use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to download and create USB images from many different Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to install many versions of Windows from a USB drive. If you currently have a Windows installation CD/DVD you can follow these instructions to make a USB drive boot:

> http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

One possible open source alternative would be to use Ubuntu. The [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)  includes detailed instructions on how to install to a USB drive under step 2 (with the heading "Burn your CD or create a USB drive").