# CD ROM drive is not working but need to reformat and reinstall

Tags: windows-xp, formatting

**Details**

- I have two partitions in my computer; C and D. I've installed
  **Windows XP** on "C".
- I want to format the "C" drive, but the problem is, ***My CD ROM drive is not
  working.***
- I have the Windows XP installation media in the CD ROM ["D"] drive.

**My questions are:**

1. Can I format the "C" drive even if my CD ROM is not working?
2. How can I install a new Windows XP without a CD ROM after formatting C if that's possible?

Comment: @JWALIT: Try pressing F8 on startup. With XP some PC manufacturers used to install a recovery partition which could be used to repair you computer. Please post back with the options that are shown.

Answer (score 3):

You, if your BIOS supports it, can install XP from a USB. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-pen-drive) for how to do it.

You say you have two partitions, C and D with a copy of the XP Install media on the D drive. I guess you want to boot the media from the D drive - that's not going to be easy, it would be better if you re-install from the USB.

Comment: well thanx for valuable suggestion bro regards......J

Answer (score 0):

Use USB drive such as pendrive.

1. First copy the installing version to your pendrive.
2. Make your pendrive bootable with the help of the software which can be found in the internet.
3. Make USB drive as the primary boot device on the BIOS setting.
4. Then enjoy