# How do I install Windows XP on a computer without cd drive?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, usb, freedos

I need to install Windows XP on a computer without a CD drive
I have the following in mind
Please suggest on whether it is feasible or not, or if it cannot work for some reason, what else I can try
The computer can be booted with USB, and I have the windows XP installation files with me
I want to copy the windows XP installation files to the D: of the computer (computer has 1 physical HDD, partitioned into C and D, with Windows XP currently on C: )

This is what I intend to do:

I will create a DOS (or FreeDOS, what ever I can manage) bootable USB, boot in tot the computer with the USB, go to the folder in D drive with the Windows XP setup file, and launch Windows XP setup winnt32.exe from command line

Will this method work? Can FreeDOS launch Windows XP setup, or do I have to make sure I get a version of MSDOS? Will any version of MSDOS work? Once the Windows XP setup is launched in this manner, does it still expect a Windows XP CD to be present on the cd drive? Can this cause any problems during setup?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked an answered [before](http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-pen-drive?rq=1).  Just boot to the USB drive.  The process you want to use WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: Unless this system is ancient (before 2000 or so) you very likely can boot from a USB attached CD-ROM drive, which are fairly cheap today.  This would be the easiest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find complete instrutions from links:

[Roderick van Domburg](http://www.vandomburg.net/installing-windows-xp-from-usb/)
and on [Weblogzz](http://weblogzz.blogspot.com/2008/01/install-windows-from-pen-drive.html) Posted by Krishna Prasad

You need to download two files for this process:

1. HpUSBformat(2MB)  or use [BartPE and PE Builder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)
2. 2.Dos Files(less than a MB) Extract the dos file and run the HpUSB format utility to format the usb thumb drive and make it bootable.
3. Run the USB utility. select the USB drive. select the check box 
           create a dos startup disk and check "using DOS system files located
           at and select the target location where you extracted the DOS files.
4. Now copy the setup files from the Win XP  [Download from Download
   Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28) Windows XP Service Pack 2
5. In the bios ,set boot priority for the USB as first and perform the
   boot.the cursor will stop with a drive.Type nc and hit enter.This
   will copy all files from usb thumb drive to disk C.

[Note: You can also install directly from the usb thumb drive by typing "cd I386" and then running "winnt".
Remove Your usb thumb drive and reboot your system.The system will enter the windows setup wizard.Then the usual routine as installing from a CD.You are done..!!!

[installing-windows-xp-from-usb](http://www.vandomburg.net/installing-windows-xp-from-usb/)

[xp-from-usb-thumb](http://www.eeeguides.com/2007/11/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-thumb.html)

or

[install-windows-from-pen-drive](http://weblogzz.blogspot.com/2008/01/install-windows-from-pen-drive.html)

[Install Windows By Booting From A USB...!!!(PART 2 for NTFS)](http://weblogzz.blogspot.com/2008/01/install-windows-by-booting-from-usbpart.html)

Comment: BartPE seems to be very slow so I want to use something else