# Install XP from thumbdrive

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)

Does anyone know how I can burn a ISO image on a thumbdrive? And also make it bootable? I'd like to install XP using a thumbdrive (computer supports booting from USB).

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive or http://superuser.com/questions/26895/easy-way-to-boot-winxp-install-cd-from-usb-pen-drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [tool from Microsoft for this](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool).

Comment: Does that only work with Windows 7?