# Install windows xp using USB: removable disk option not available in boot device options list

Tags: windows-xp

I want to install windows xp with pendrive as my dvdrom doesnt work. When i go to bios setup and boot device options,i cant find any option for pendrive.Here's my boot device options:

```
    >1st FLOPPY DRIVE
    >3M-HDS728080PLA
    >PS-ASUS DVD-E818A
    >DISABLED
```

And Here's my desktop configuration:

```
    intel(R)
    pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.66GHz
    0.99GB RAM
```

N.B: I bought my desktop in 2006.

Now how can i install windows xp in my desktop using pendrive?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that older BIOS versions require for USB pendrive to be inserted before starting up your computer in order for them to be recognized and added on the list of possible boot devices. Besides that, there are some BIOS versions that show boot devices list order - this means that you should connect the pendrive, startup your computes, open BIOS boot options and go through the settings and try to find your pendrive listed there. After you confirm that the pendrive is listed in boot devices, place it on the 1st place on the list so that it will have the priority over your cd/dvd player, hard disk etc. Save settings and exit. Reboot and follow the on screen instructions :)

Additional help can be found on [Easy way to boot WinXP install CD from USB pen drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/26895/easy-way-to-boot-winxp-install-cd-from-usb-pen-drive?rq=1)

Let me know if this was helpful to you.

Comment: You may also need to enable 'Boot from USB' for it to appear in the device list.